# subsetting a dataframe into temporally related events

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have a DF containing illness records sourced from multiple data sources. Each illness is given by a illness code and each has a time_to_code variable as continuous variables.

As there are multiple datasources, and subjects can have multiple codes all occuring at the same time (multiple illnesses diagnosed at once) or the same illness recorded in different places.

I wish to generate columns of unique 'events'. An event would be the timepoint of an illness code, but if there is another code that has occurred within 0.25 of this then it would be considered the same event. The events would then be in wide format for each subject from event_1 to event_X (as many as there are) ordered from smallest value to largest value. The value provided in event_1 would be the lowest "time_to" that had constituted that column.

For instance, if subject_1 had illnesses at time 15.611, 15.623, 17.22 and 17.23 this would be considered as 2 events, with the event_1 column showing 15.611 and event_2 column showing 17.22.

Below is a reproducible dataframe:

```
# Set seed for reproducibility
set.seed(123)

# Number of rows and columns
n_rows <- 10
n_cols <- 20

# Generate unique ID column
ID <- 1:n_rows

# Generate random time to code columns with NAs
time_to_code <- replicate(n_cols, {
  times <- sample(c(round(runif(n_rows - 3, min = 16, max = 75), 3), rep(NA, 3)), n_rows)
  sample(c(times, rep(NA, n_rows - 3)), n_rows)
})

# Combine ID and time to code columns into a dataframe
df <- data.frame(ID, time_to_code)

# Rename the time_to_code columns
colnames(df)[-1] <- paste0("Time_to_code_", letters[1:(n_cols-1)])
```

I have struggled quite a lot with this, I have managed to say if they have multiple events, and how many events they have had (I hope and please correct if not!) with the below code.

```
df$Multiple_Injuries <- apply(df[, grepl("Time_to_code_", colnames(df))], 1, function(x) {
  n_entries <- sum(!is.na(x))
  n_diff_gt_1 <- sum(diff(na.omit(x)) > 0.25)
  if (n_entries >= 2 && n_diff_gt_1 >= 1) {
    return("Yes")
  } else {
    return("No")
  }
})

df$Number_of_injuries <- apply(df[, grepl("Time_to_code_", colnames(df))], 1, function(x) {
  n_columns_with_entry <- sum(!is.na(x))
  diffs <- diff(na.omit(x))
  n_diffs_gt_quarter <- sum(diffs > 0.25)
  if (n_columns_with_entry > 1 && n_diffs_gt_quarter > 0) {
    return(n_columns_with_entry)
  } else {
    return(1)
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is pivot the data longer, remove missing values, order the data within ID by time-to-code, then remove any time-to-code values such that the lagged value is less than .25 away.  Finally, generate event numbers and pivot the data wider again.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
  
set.seed(123)

# Number of rows and columns
n_rows <- 10
n_cols <- 20

# Generate unique ID column
ID <- 1:n_rows

# Generate random time to code columns with NAs
time_to_code <- replicate(n_cols, {
  times <- sample(c(round(runif(n_rows - 3, min = 16, max = 75), 3), rep(NA, 3)), n_rows)
  sample(c(times, rep(NA, n_rows - 3)), n_rows)
})

# Combine ID and time to code columns into a dataframe
df <- data.frame(ID, time_to_code)

# Rename the time_to_code columns
colnames(df)[-1] <- paste0("Time_to_code_", letters[1:(n_cols-1)])
#> Warning in colnames(df)[-1] <- paste0("Time_to_code_", letters[1:(n_cols - :
#> number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
```

```r
df %>% pivot_longer(-ID, 
                    names_pattern="Time_to_code_(.*)", 
                    names_to = "evname", 
                    values_to = "ttc") %>% 
  na.omit() %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  arrange(ttc, .by_group=TRUE) %>% 
  mutate(new_event = ifelse(ttc - lag(ttc) < .25, 0, 1), 
         new_event = ifelse(row_number() == 1, 1, new_event)) %>% 
  filter(new_event == 1) %>% 
  mutate(event_num = cumsum(new_event)) %>%
  select(-new_event) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from="event_num", values_from = "ttc", names_prefix="event_")
#> # A tibble: 86 × 15
#> # Groups:   ID [10]
#>       ID evname event_1 event_2 event_3 event_4 event_5 event_6 event_7 event_8
#>    <int> <chr>    <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
#>  1     1 n         25.8    NA      NA      NA      NA      NA        NA      NA
#>  2     1 l         NA      28.3    NA      NA      NA      NA        NA      NA
#>  3     1 d         NA      NA      33.8    NA      NA      NA        NA      NA
#>  4     1 i         NA      NA      NA      39.4    NA      NA        NA      NA
#>  5     1 b         NA      NA      NA      NA      60.7    NA        NA      NA
#>  6     1 j         NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      63.4      NA      NA
#>  7     1 e         NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA        66      NA
#>  8     2 s         18.6    NA      NA      NA      NA      NA        NA      NA
#>  9     2 k         NA      23.0    NA      NA      NA      NA        NA      NA
#> 10     2 h         NA      NA      31.2    NA      NA      NA        NA      NA
#> # ℹ 76 more rows
#> # ℹ 5 more variables: event_9 <dbl>, event_10 <dbl>, event_11 <dbl>,
#> #   event_12 <dbl>, event_13 <dbl>
```

<sup>Created on 2023-06-15 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Here is a data.table implementation. As far as I understand, your example data does not provide any instances where events are within 0.25 (I use a helper function `f()` where the default threshold  is 0.25, but a different value could be passed):

```
library(data.table)

f <- \(v,x=0.25) c(x,diff(v))>=x
e <- \(v) paste0("event_", sprintf("%02.0f", cumsum(v)))

dcast(
  melt(df, "ID")[order(ID,value)][, tag:=f(value), ID][tag==T, event:=e(tag), ID][!is.na(event)],
  ID~event,
  value.var = "value"
)
```

Output:

```
       ID event_01 event_02 event_03 event_04 event_05 event_06 event_07 event_08 event_09 event_10 event_11 event_12 event_13
    <int>    <num>    <num>    <num>    <num>    <num>    <num>    <num>    <num>    <num>    <num>    <num>    <num>    <num>
 1:     1   25.766   28.324   33.773   39.398   60.749   63.366   66.000       NA       NA       NA       NA       NA       NA
 2:     2   18.605   23.045   31.176   34.773   38.986   51.066   51.915   57.350   67.122       NA       NA       NA       NA
 3:     3   21.407   24.425   28.987   29.274   32.287   37.843   39.344   52.259   53.002   58.083   68.098   68.622   73.077
 4:     4   28.759   34.218   40.130   41.950   57.806   59.196   60.597   67.065   72.885       NA       NA       NA       NA
 5:     5   30.107   34.982   44.190   49.460   53.124   59.171   62.128   65.307   66.392   66.746       NA       NA       NA
 6:     6   16.037   24.678   30.498   38.911   42.227   44.914   47.492   50.323   50.990   62.510   72.087   73.773       NA
 7:     7   20.869   27.329   30.925   39.537   40.385   43.415   60.537   69.952       NA       NA       NA       NA       NA
 8:     8   24.679   34.434   36.761   42.831   44.069   63.958   73.192       NA       NA       NA       NA       NA       NA
 9:     9   20.525   26.133   28.817   33.731   40.128   61.701       NA       NA       NA       NA       NA       NA       NA
10:    10   17.083   17.452   44.229   47.036   59.418   70.106       NA       NA       NA       NA       NA       NA       NA
```

If you define events as the same if the threshold was 3.5, then you can pass that value to `f()`, and  would get the following:

```
dcast(
  melt(df, "ID")[order(ID,value)][, tag:=f(value,4.5), ID][tag==T, event:=e(tag), ID][!is.na(event)],
  ID~event,
  value.var = "value"
)

       ID event_01 event_02 event_03 event_04 event_05 event_06
    <int>    <num>    <num>    <num>    <num>    <num>    <num>
 1:     1   25.766   33.773   39.398   60.749       NA       NA
 2:     2   18.605   31.176   51.066   57.350   67.122       NA
 3:     3   21.407   28.987   37.843   52.259   58.083   68.098
 4:     4   28.759   34.218   40.130   57.806   67.065   72.885
 5:     5   30.107   34.982   44.190   49.460   59.171       NA
 6:     6   16.037   24.678   30.498   38.911   62.510   72.087
 7:     7   20.869   27.329   39.537   60.537   69.952       NA
 8:     8   24.679   34.434   42.831   63.958   73.192       NA
 9:     9   20.525   26.133   33.731   40.128   61.701       NA
10:    10   17.083   44.229   59.418   70.106       NA       NA
```